# d3.js How to get sum of array of objects data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have the csv file

```
DATE OF ARREST, ARREST RESOLUTION, COUNT
01/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 1
01/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 1
01/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 1
02/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 1
02/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 1
```

I want to create a chart view with the data above. To do this, I have to sum "COUNT" for each date. For example, I need to have     01/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 3 ... in this day I have 3 cases. To parse the date I use

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

 data.forEach(
  function(d){
  d.count = +d["COUNT"];
  d.date = parseDate(d["DATE OF ARREST"]);
})
```

The chart shows the year correctly, but the number of cases is always 1. How can I count the "COUNT" for each year?

Comment: You can't make a histogram with that variable (`"date of arrest"`), which is not quantitative (unless you're measuring the *duration* of the time). Can you show the histogram generator (in v4, it is `d3.histogram`) of your code?. Are you really making a histogram, or is this a bar chart?

Comment: Why is the number of cases called `price`? That sounds strange. Is `price` the indicator of your graph?

Comment: @trincot  uploaded the code....the variable is "count".

Comment: @VasilescuCatalin that makes no difference, you can name it the way you want. What about the histogram generator?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have to create a timeline histogram view...To do this I use a normal chart with points. On the x axis are the "years" and on the y axis the number of records. There is a difference? Instead of points I could use a bar chart

Comment: So, do you have an histogram generator or not?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I use a normal chart

Comment: @Vasilescu Catalin Do you want your data has this structure: `[{ date: <appropriate day>, count: <sum all COUNT for the appropriate day> },...`?

Comment: Ok, so you don't have any histogram here... I just edited your question removing the reference to "histogram".

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov Something la this {01/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 3}, {02/01/1988, BONDED OUT, 2} .. If there are 5 cases at date 01/01/2001....count is 5.

Comment: @Vasilescu Catalin Ok, look at my answer. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert your data and sum all `COUNT` for the same day. You can do it with [d3.nest](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest).

```js
var dataAsCsv = `DATE OF ARREST,ARREST RESOLUTION,COUNT
01/01/1988,BONDED OUT,1
01/01/1988,BONDED OUT,1
01/01/1988,BONDED OUT,1
02/01/1988,BONDED OUT,1
02/01/1988,BONDED OUT,1`;

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

var convertedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d["DATE OF ARREST"]; })
  .rollup(function(v) {
      return {
        date: parseDate(v[0]["DATE OF ARREST"]),
        count: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return +d["COUNT"]; })
      }
  })
  .entries(data).map(function(d) { return d.value});

console.log(convertedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I need. Can I use the code   insided3.csv("Urbana_Police_Arrests_Since_1988.csv", function(error, data) {
...
    } ); ?

Comment: Probably yes. Try it. I got `data` with `d3.csvParse`, you will get `data` as the second argument of the callback function. If the structure of  csv the same it should works.